# How to resolve “Target closed” error using nodeJS and Puppeteer in docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer

i am trying to generate pdf file using puppeteer which is being setup inside docker.
however i keep getting error

Error in pdf ::---> Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed.
at /usr/src/filemanager/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:183:56

```
const getPdfFile = async (url) => {
  let browser = null
  let result

  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage"],
      headless: true
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
    await page.emulateMediaType('screen')
    result = await page.pdf(defaultPrintOptions)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error in pdf ::--->', error)
    throw error
  } finally {
    if (browser !== null) {
      await browser.close()
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

this works on my local machine environment with same docker setup however failing when deployed to cloud.
i am failing to understand what mistake is being made here by me.

package.json --> "puppeteer": "^2.1.1"
docker container -->

```
nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.7-nodejs12-stretch
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 libxtst6 \ 
    --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```